# How to pass environment variable values into files in the docker container I'm trying to run

Tags: docker, environment-variables, credentials

Let's say I have a config file in my docker container located here:

/opt/jboss/bin/config.xml

The Config file looks like this:

```
<Database-Password>$PASSWORD</Database-Password>
```

I want to pass the actual password in when I go to run the docker container using the "--env-file" argument.

This is the contents on the env-file I'm passing in:

```
PASSWORD=MyPassword
```

I understand the VARIABLE=VALUE syntax. "MyPassword" is the value of the Password variable.

How will docker know to find the specific file (/opt/jboss/bin/config.xml) with this variable and swap it out? Am I declaring the variable correctly in the config file? For some reason I'm having trouble finding this information.

Comment: You question is not clear, try to make it better.

Comment: as your xml file does not have the expected syntax, docker will ignore it

Comment: What is the expected syntax? If I just put "PASSWORD" instead of "$PASSWORD" in the XML file, will that work?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is - it won't necessarily. Unless you have some mechanism to rewrite your config file from the host environment.

This is pretty easy in a shell script - you can just refer to it as you have done.

But an XML file isn't "run" in that sense, so it *probably* won't just work.

As an example - if you want to 'edit' your xml, you could do it with `perl` - but you'll have to install a bit more stuff to get it to work:

```
perl -MXML::Twig -e'XML::Twig -> new ( twig_handlers => { Database-Password => sub { $_ -> set_text ( $ENV{PASSWORD} ) } } ) -> parsefile_inplace("/opt/jboss/bin/config.xml")'
```

(This will need both `perl` and `XML::Twig` installing, so there may be better options)

Comment: Right, well the container actually starts up an application server which uses the credentials in the config.xml file to connect

Comment: Sure, but it likely wont expand the variable `$PASSWORD` unless explicitly told to do so. You'd need some way of expanding it before trying to use the configuration else it will literally see "$PASSWORD".

Comment: you will need some shell scripting, extract what is in your file between `<Database-Password>` and `</Database-Password>` write it in a file on a line that begins with`Password=` or so

Answer (score 0):

the syntax in your env file should be

`variable=value`

see the doc at  https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

extract

`cat ./env.list
TEST_FOO=BAR`